# Is metrizability preserved by continuous mapping?

Tags: general-topology

> Let f be a continuous mapping of a metrizable space (X,τ) onto a topological space (Y,τ1). Is (Y,τ1) necessarily metrizable?

My instinct tell me that it's false, but I could think of counter example, please give me some idea.

Comment: If you give $X$ the discrete topology (corresponding to the metric $d(x,y) = \delta_{x,y}$ - the Kronecker Delta), then every function is continuous.  In particular, let $Y$ be the same set as $X$, but with a non-metrizable topology, and look at the identity function $id:X \to X$.

Comment: There's no reason for $Y$ to even be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to recap my comment above:

Let $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x = y \\ 1 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ This induces the discrete topology on $X$.  For any topological space $Y$, and any map $f: X \to Y$, $f$ is continuous.  Therefore, just take any surjective function from a discrete space to a nonmetrizable space and you're golden.

Comment: But by definition of metric, d(x,y)=0 iff x=y.

Comment: Oops, that should be a $\neq$. Good catch.